# Como travar a tela de fundo e permitir apenas o Scrooll no menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Eu to com um problema aqui, eu criei um menu que tem rolagem, porém quando tenho que rolar, preciso que a tela de fundo fique travada e apenas role na medida do menu... Aqui estão as fotos:
[image: Imagem do menu]

[image: Menu com o que aparece]

O código é o seguinte: 
**HTML** (A partir do div="content o código se mantém igual")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Notícias</title>

    <meta charset=UTF-8> <!-- ISO-8859-1 -->
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name=description content="Introdução à produção de sites responsivos">
    <meta name=keywords content=""> <!-- Opcional -->
    <meta name=author content='Equipe 05'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:480px)" href="css/style480/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:480px)" href="css/style480/carrosselPagCurso.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:480px)" href="css/style480/stylePagCursos480.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:480px)" href="css/style480/footer480.css">

<!--<link rel=stylesheet media="screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px)" href="css/style768.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet media="screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px)" href="css/style1024.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet media="screen and (min-width:1025px)" href="css/style1366.css">
-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/fiebIVazio.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="container">
        <header>  
            <nav> 
                <a href="landpageMobile.html">  <img src="imagens/fiebIVazio.png" id="iconTop" alt=""> </a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check">
                <label id="icone" for="check"></label>
                <div id="menu">
                    <span></span>
                </div>    
                    <div class="barra"> 
                        <nav id="navMenu">
                             <a href="landpageMobile.html"><div class="link">Home</div></a>
                             <a href="cursos480.html"><div class="link">Cursos</div></a>
                             <a href="unidades480.html"><div class="link">Unidades</div></a>
                             <a href="noticias480.html"><div class="link">Notícias</div></a>
                             <a href="vestib480.html"><div class="link">Vestibulinho</div></a>
                             <a href="test480.html"><div class="link">Teste Vocacional</div></a>
                             <a href="contat480.html"><div class="link">Contato</div></a>
                             <a href="cadastro480.html"><div class="link">Cadastrar</div></a>
                             <a href="login480.html"><div class="link">Login</div></a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </nav>
         </header>
```

**CSS do Botão** (Eu fiz o código do botão em css)

```
#check{
    display:none;
}
#icone{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-left: 63.2%;
    margin-top: 4%;
}
.barra{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:  center;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
#navMenu{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#navMenu a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.link{
    background-color:#494950;
    padding: 9.4%;
    font-family:"arial";
    font-size: 18pt;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    color:#f4f4f9;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
    opacity:0;
}
.link:hover{
    background-color:#050542;
}

#check:checked ~ .barra #navMenu a .link{
    opacity:1;
    margin-top: 0%;
    visibility: visible;
}
label{
    width: 46px;
    float: left;
    opacity:0;
    height: 44px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow:5px 2px 23px;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
label:hovert + #menu{
    opacity: 1;
}
#menu{
    width: 43px;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0.6;
    height: 43px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4c0c3f;
    box-shadow: 5px 2px 23px;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 84%;
    z-index: 4;
    margin-top: 4%;
}
#check{
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index: 4;
}
span{
    width: 59%;
    height: 7%;
    top: 47%;
    left: 21%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.1 linear;
}
span:before{
    content:'';
    top: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
span:after{
    content:'';
    bottom: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#check:checked + label + div > span{
    background-color: transparent;
}
#check:checked + label + div > span:after{
    transform: translate(0px, 6px) rotate(45deg);
}
#check:checked + label + div > span:before{
    transform: translate(0px, -8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
#check:checked + label + div > .tent{
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**Se precisar de algo é só falar**

Ps: Ja tentei colocar isso mas não deu certo:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#check:checked > body{
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Cara mas com o código que vc postou na pergunta o menu está muito longe de estar igual ao da imagem... Na verdade ele nem está funcionando a ponto de podermos simular o seu problema para tentar uma solução...

Comment: Eu tinha dado uma diminuida no código pra facilitar a compreensão, mas não sabia que não deu certo, então agora postei o código completo do menu

Answer (score -3):

Tenta colocar isso no background que você quer que fique fixado:

`background-attachment: fixed;`